# Pythonic Way of replacing Multiple Characters

Tags: python, string

I've created a onetime function

```
a = lambda x: x.replace('\n', '')
b = lambda y: y.replace('\t', '').strip()
c = lambda x: b(a(x))
```

Is there a **Pythonic** and *compact* way (*one liner?*) to this to improve readability and performance. Mainly performance.

(note: I know I can do `lambda x: x.replace('\n').replace('\t\).strip()` but doesn't do anything. Preferably there's a built-in method that deals with this type of issue that I wasn't aware of and I know that the performance improvements are negligible.)

Input: 
`'my \t\t\t test, case \ntest\n LoremIpsum'`

Desired Output:
`'my  test, case test LoremIpsum'`

Comment: Can you provide some context of what the end result it? Initial thought is that you pass a list of characters to remove to a function.

Comment: 'my \t test \n text' output: 'my test text'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
`str.translate`
For starters, if you're replacing a lot of characters with the same thing, I'd 100% recommend `str.translate`.

```
>>> from string import whitespace as wsp
>>> '\n\ttext   \there\r'.translate(str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(wsp, '')))
'texthere'
```

This syntax is valid with python-3.x only. For python-2.x, you will need to `import string` and use `string.maketrans` to build the mapping instead.

If you want to exclude whitespace chars itself, then

```
wsp = set(wsp) - {' '}
```

---

**Option 2**
`re.sub`
The regex equivalent of the above would be using `re.sub`.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', '', '\n\ttext   \there\r')
'texthere'
```

However, performance wise, `str.translate` beats this hands down.

Comment: Also, a more general regex equivalent that does not rely specifically on a metaclass such as `\s` would use `[..]` for a custom list of the specific characters to remove. (But I like you use of `translate` more!)

Comment: @usr2564301 Sure, character classes would be a good alternative if OP wanted to customise their replacements. Something similar would also be needed for option 1.

Comment: Yeah, I was considering regex but because of the performance, I wanted another solution. Also, note that I did not want to replace ' ' the space char itself. If you could edit 1st method to do that would be awesome.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ No, thank you. You're awesome, you're very responsive and diligent with your answers, I appreciate that!

Comment: @ElvirMuslic Likewise, thank you for contributing to the community! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The improvements are pretty straightforward:

**Drop lambdas.** `str.replace()` method is a function, and in the first line of your snippet you define a function that calls to another function and nothing else. Why do you need the wrapping lambda? The same concerns the second line.

**Use return values.** Actually, in [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=string%20replace#string.replace) we see:

> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new.

So you can do a first `replace()`, then do a second one *on the obtained result*.

To sum up, you'll have:

```
c = x.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').strip()
```

Note: if you have many characters to remove, you'd better use `str.translate()` but for two of them `str.replace()` is far more readable.

Cheers!

Comment: I understand that but obviously, I wanted a compact solution that's why I used lambdas as a way to intuitively apply those methods to a string. Thank you for your answer.